# Pandas: divide data to 15min period

Tags: pandas, timedelta

I have dataframe and date looks like

```
event_time
2017-01-17 00:12:50      
2016-12-05 01:00:21      
2016-12-04 01:14:36     
2016-12-04 01:04:03     
2016-12-04 02:28:23     
2016-12-04 02:46:49      
2016-12-04 01:58:04
```

I need to get column `period`, where 15 min starts from `00:00:00` and day, month and year don't important.
time in `00:00:00 - 00:15:00` - period 1
`00:15:01 - 00:50:00` - period 2, etc.
If I use `df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='15Min'))` it works wrong, because it use also day. But I need to use only time.

Desire output

```
event_time            period
2017-01-17 00:12:50   1      
2016-12-05 01:00:21   4    
2016-12-04 01:14:36   4 
2016-12-04 01:04:03   4 
2016-12-04 02:28:23   10  
2016-12-04 02:46:49   12 
2016-12-04 01:58:04   8
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime([
    "2017-01-17 00:12:50",    
    "2016-12-05 01:00:21",      
    "2016-12-04 01:14:36",     
    "2016-12-04 01:04:03",     
    "2016-12-04 02:28:23",     
    "2016-12-04 02:46:49",      
    "2016-12-04 01:58:04"]),
    columns=['timestamp']
    )
```

and then `period` column

```
df['period'] = df.timestamp.apply(lambda ts: 1 + ts.hour * 4 + ts.minute // 15)
```

which gives following input:

```
            timestamp  period
0 2017-01-17 00:12:50       1
1 2016-12-05 01:00:21       5
2 2016-12-04 01:14:36       5
3 2016-12-04 01:04:03       5
4 2016-12-04 02:28:23      10
5 2016-12-04 02:46:49      12
6 2016-12-04 01:58:04       8
```

There is small discrepancy between your and mine output - rows `1`, `2` and `3`: for example `01:00:21` should be `5` because there are four periods in first hour and 5th just begun.

Comment: I need to add it column with numeric value

Comment: can you update your question with desired output then?

Comment: I need number of period in column 'period'. Your code returns number of period, but to time `00:05:05` it return 32

Comment: again, I'm guessing. If my edited response isn't what you are looking for, without example I won't be able to help you.

Comment: I need no sum) I need to get column with number of period. I have changed my question and added desire output

Answer (score 1):

New solution with [`dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html) and [`dt.minute`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.minute.html):

```
df['label'] = df['event_time'].dt.hour * 4 + df['event_time'].dt.minute // 15 + 1
print (df)
           event_time  label
0 2017-01-17 00:12:50      1
1 2016-12-05 01:00:21      5
2 2016-12-04 01:14:36      5
3 2016-12-04 01:04:03      5
4 2016-12-04 02:28:23     10
5 2016-12-04 02:46:49     12
6 2016-12-04 01:58:04      8
```

**Timings**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=100000, freq='27T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': rng})  

df['label'] = df['timestamp'].dt.hour * 4 + df['timestamp'].dt.minute // 15 + 1
df['period'] = df.timestamp.apply(lambda ts: 1 + ts.hour * 4 + ts.minute // 15)
print (df)

In [172]: %timeit df['timestamp'].dt.hour * 4 + df['timestamp'].dt.minute // 15 + 1
10 loops, best of 3: 20.2 ms per loop

In [173]: %timeit df.timestamp.apply(lambda ts: 1 + ts.hour * 4 + ts.minute // 15)
1 loop, best of 3: 301 ms per loop
```

Old solution (working, but a bit complicated):

You can first convert `datetimes` to [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and then convert to seconds by [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html).

Then use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) or [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
df['tot'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['event_time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
              .dt.total_seconds()
              .astype(int)

#necessary add one group
bins = np.concatenate([np.arange(24 * 4) * 900, np.array([100000])])
labels = np.arange(1, 24 * 4 + 1)
df['label'] = pd.cut(df['tot'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

---

```
df = df.assign(label1=np.searchsorted(bins, df['tot']))
print (df)
           event_time    tot label  label1
0 2017-01-17 00:12:50    770     1       1
1 2016-12-05 01:00:21   3621     5       5
2 2016-12-04 01:14:36   4476     5       5
3 2016-12-04 01:04:03   3843     5       5
4 2016-12-04 02:28:23   8903    10      10
5 2016-12-04 02:46:49  10009    12      12
6 2016-12-04 01:58:04   7084     8       8
```

Similar solutions, only works with `Series` tot:

```
tot = pd.to_timedelta(df['event_time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
       .dt.total_seconds()
       .astype(int)

bins = np.concatenate([np.arange(24 * 4) * 900, np.array([100000])])
labels = np.arange(1, 24 * 4 + 1)
df['label'] = pd.cut(tot, bins=bins, labels=labels)

df = df.assign(label1=np.searchsorted(bins, tot))
print (df)
           event_time label  label1
0 2017-01-17 00:12:50     1       1
1 2016-12-05 01:00:21     5       5
2 2016-12-04 01:14:36     5       5
3 2016-12-04 01:04:03     5       5
4 2016-12-04 02:28:23    10      10
5 2016-12-04 02:46:49    12      12
6 2016-12-04 01:58:04     8       8
```

Comment: Did you noticed that I have given the same answer before you did in your **update** with identical solution (different notation)? That's hardly fair.

Comment: @mkos - I think it is not same solution, so I add it. apply vs vectorized aprocha is always different.

Comment: @mkos - but idea is same, you are right. And i think it is no problem.

Comment: vectorized approach is ~3x slower (on my PC) than `apply()`, so why bother updating?

Comment: @mkos - it is faster, because test small dataframe. Check my edited answer - apply is slowier.